# To create a fragment that holds a view, must one always override the Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

When creating a Fragment that holds a view programmatically, must one always extend the fragment class and override the OnCreateView method. Is there another simpler way to do this (like creating a fragment and passing it the view id or something).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is true, it is required to create separated class extended a Fragment. But still you can pass viewId as argument. It is required by system to be able to re-instantiate the fragment when it is necessary. I'd do that like this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final ViewFragment newInstance(int contentId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("contentId", contentId);
        ViewFragment fragment = new ViewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int contentId = args.getInt("contentId");
        return inflater.inflate(contentId, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing at the moment.